# Firefox 14 breaks 3D 'card flip' effect - anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

Built a site where a large part of it relies on flipping DIVs over with a 3D effect, upgraded to FF14 yesterday morning and the effect was broken. It works fine in FF13, Chrome, IE9, etc.

I can't post the site I'm working on, but this site is broken in exactly the same way - it jumps between the front and back of the card rather than rotating

http://jigoshop.com/product-category/extensions/

Anyone have any ideas?

---

**EDIT: OK, probably should've included more info**

I'm using this plug-in to handle the flipping

http://www.zachstronaut.com/projects/rotate3di/

I was wrong when I said it was the same technique as that other website as that appears to be plain CSS whereas this plug-in is for jQuery. Here's a link to a demo I threw together

http://olliesilviotti.co.uk/the-laboratory/cards/demo/

---

**EDIT: This is how the query is used:**

```
$('#boxes .box div.back').hide().css('left', 0);

            function mySideChange(front) {
                if (front) {
                    $(this).parent().find('div.front').show();
                    $(this).parent().find('div.back').hide();

                } else {
                    $(this).parent().find('div.front').hide();
                    $(this).parent().find('div.back').show();
                }
            }


            $('#boxes .box').live('mouseover', function() {
                if (!$(this).data('init')) {
                    $(this).data('init', true);
                    $(this).hoverIntent({
                        over: function () {
                            $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('flip', 250, {direction: 'clockwise', sideChange: mySideChange});
                        },
                        timeout: 1,
                        out: function () {
                            $(this).find('div').stop().rotate3Di('unflip', 500, {sideChange: mySideChange});
                        }
                    });
                    $(this).trigger('mouseover');
                }
            });
```

The markup looks like this:

```
<div id="boxes">
        <div class="box floated-box">
                <div class="front">Random Number</div>
                <div class="back">I am the back of the card</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's broken on FF 17a as well.

Comment: Would be nice to have some example markup and where you call it, but I'll check the plugin's source.

Comment: I've added the markup and the jQuery now. I assumed it wouldn't be needed as it'd be the way FF now handles transformations rather than the plugin

Comment: If it worked on FF13 and doesn't work on FF14, why don't you report this on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/)?

Comment: Wanted to check there wasn't something new that I was supposed to be doing/it wasn't just me before posting it as a bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually because Firefox follows latest standards. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_14_for_developers

> As it has been removed from the draft standard, support for the skew()
>   function has been removed from transform property.

(This causes the entire `-moz-transform` declaration is dropped.)

Instead of reporting bug to Bugzilla, I'd say it should be reported to author of the plugin.

Comment: Makes perfect sense why my console keeps spamming `Error in parsing value for 'transform'.  Declaration dropped.` constantly. +1 for the nice find.

Comment: Ok cool, that make sense (but is more than a little annoying).

Are you aware of any other way to simulate this 3D affect without using skew?

Comment: @ollie I'd give 3D transforms a try, but I've never used them. Please be aware that 3D transforms spec has also changed recently so support may vary.